# I am currently configuring my Neovim setup, but I am only get it to work as a root user

Tags: neovim, lua, iterm2, packer

Basically, I am creating a .config/nvim for Neovim on my M1 Macbook Pro (Monterey 12.6), and I using the iTerm2 terminal emulator. I am having to create the entire configuration as a root user because the OS otherwise gives me a `permission denied` message whenever I run commends like `mkdir` in the `.config` folder. So, I am first running `sudo -s` and then setting up my Neovim configuration. When I first set it up and run it, it works, but the catch is that it only works if I am a root user. (This also puzzles me a lot because whenever I see tutorials on YouTube everyone is able to `mkdir` and create files without running `sudo -s` on their M1 MacOS in iTerm2) When I exit out of `sudo` and run `nvim` normally, I get the following error (something about my 'packpath'):

```
Error detected while processing /Users/abhinavmara/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...s/abhinavmara/.config/nvim/lua/maestro/plugins-setup.lua:6: Vim(packadd):E919: Directory not f
ound in 'packpath': "pack/*/opt/packer.nvim"
```

And I am also getting the exact same error in another file called `packer_compiled.lua` which is just the file that gets automatically created when `packer` is initially created.
I am also getting an error about a ShaDa file `permission denied`:

```
E886: System error while opening ShaDa file /Users/abhinavmara/.local/state/nvim/shada/main.shada for reading: permission denied
```

I looked in my the path that was shown in error `E5113` (the one about packpath), and I have nothing in the `../opt` directory, and I have all my plugins in the `../start` directory and that is where the `packer.nvim` exists as well. I have tried moving the `packer.nvim` into the `../opt` directory but I still get the same errors. I have also tried doing the following:

```
vim.o.packpath = vim.o.packpath .. "," .. "~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/opt/packer.nvim"
```

But that also gives me the exact same errors.

I am just wondering what exactly I need to do how I have to configure Neovim so that I can use it without being a root user (as that can be very dangerous).

Comment: I strongly suggest taking a close look at the permissions on all the directories in `~/.local` and `~/.config` or even `~`. (For example: `ls -l`.) You may need to `sudo chown` those back to yourself. You should never need `sudo` to edit your personal config. Have you run `sudo vim` or similar before? It's possible that caused a problem; use `sudoedit` instead.

Comment: Ok, so I have changed the `.config`,`.local`, and all the `nvim`-related directories within to myself instead of root so that I can change them without called `sudo`. That managed to solve my problem of not being able to open or run `nvim` to make files in the `.config` and the issues with the Shada file, but I still have issues with the 'packpath' (E5113). Anything else that I can do to solve that issue? Let me know if I need to post and give any other information...

Comment: The packpath issue might be related or might not be; check the (permissions on the) directories in `:put =split(&packpath, ',')`

Comment: It has worked. I looked into the permissions for the `.local` directory where the `packer.nvim` exists and just looked into whatever error it threw again to and set myself to the user by called `sudo chown [username] [directory/file]`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please add an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments with [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble): Check all your directory permissions again:

- list files with permissions (`find ~/.local ~/.config -ls`)
- [`sudo chown` them to your user, if you need to](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/i-am-currently-configuring-my-neovim-setup-but-i-am-only-get-it-to-work-as-a-ro/44312#comment71769_39163)
- [you may need to check the directories in your `packpath`, too, which you can see in `:new | put =split(&packpath, ',')`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/i-am-currently-configuring-my-neovim-setup-but-i-am-only-get-it-to-work-as-a-ro/44312#comment71767_39163)
- [make sure you don't run `sudo vim` or similar; use `sudoedit` or `sudo -e` instead](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/i-am-currently-configuring-my-neovim-setup-but-i-am-only-get-it-to-work-as-a-ro/44312#comment71754_39163)

Comment: Maybe you could be more explicitly about what you propose and separate better the answer from the references